# The type "FrameworkAppContextSwitches" is not accessible

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application.  I am attempting to adjust the style for `TextBox`.  I used "Style Snooper" to grab the default style for that control and pasted it in the App.xaml file in my project (I have also done this for the `CheckBox` and `Button` styles).

I get the following error:

> The type "FrameworkAppContextSwitches" is not accessible.

On the following line of code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(msi:FrameworkAppContextSwitches.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering)}" Value="false" xmlns:msi="clr-namespace:MS.Internal;assembly=PresentationFramework">
```

I can post the rest of the style code if you need, but it's like 150 lines long so I didn't want to clutter up my question.

The beginning of the App.xaml file looks like this (no reference to `msi:`):

```
<Application x:Class="PartsBookAssembler.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PartsBookAssembler"
         xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
```

What namespace reference do I need?  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Correct, I've done my research, but I have not been able to find any information on what package that actually is supposed to be referencing.  As far as I can tell it's `MS.Internal` but attempting to add references to that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated my question to be more specific.  I would have preferred that you bring your concerns about my question to my attention before down-voting.  I'm just trying to get help.  I have followed all SE guidelines.  I would not have asked the question if I hadn't done my due diligence in researching it myself first.